# How to enable auto launch of Android application programmatically for oneplus3 devices

Tags: android, oneplusthree

OnePlus3 devices with Nougat version is by default blacklisting Android application because of which if you have any broadcast receiver inside your application it will never get called in case the application is cleared from background. I have not seen such issue on other device manufacturers. I have further explored it, so came to know that onePlus is doing it to restrict the background processing and improve the battery consumption. However I want my application to be auto launched without doing it manually like going to Settings -> Apps -> Gear-Symbol -> Auto Launch ->enable app.

Comment: "Xiomi is doing something like" if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

Comment: Facing same issue

Comment: It can work only with Xiomi devices . for one plus 3 the package name  "com.miui.securitycenter" will be different and we are not aware about that. as i have alredy written to one plus 3 manufacturing team , they have not yet responded.

Comment: Even this approach for xiomi will just open auto launch settings screen, where user has to switch on auto launch mode for our app, right? What I need is by default switch on auto launch mode as soon as my app is installed which is already happening for some apps like Allo, skype, etc.

Comment: I too have the same problem did you manage to get any reply from one plus

Comment: @Bikash i have not recieved any response from them till date.

Comment: @Bikash did you got any reply from One Plus team till now.

Comment: No did not get any reply from Oneplus3 team

Comment: did you receive any reply now?

Comment: @iqballone any new answer?

Comment: Sorry guys i did not receive any response from oneplus on this